# interpreting within group correlation magnitude (Multilevel Modelling)

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to get a basic understanding of how to interpret the magnitude of within group correlations- and whether the general rule of weak (.2 to .4), moderate (.4 to .6), strong (.6 to .8) and very strong (.8 to 1) commonly used for between group correlations still applies.

For a bit of context: I am running correlations for Multilevel Modelling data (Experience Sampling Methods, variables are nested by persons, so within group refers to the variance of a specific variable for each individual). I have used the R psych package to run analyses.

Would anyone be able to either provide a general "rule of thumb" or point me to a reference paper. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer here. The only rule of thumb is that an intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) > 0 is indication that you need to somehow account for the correlations of observations from the same individual or group. As an education researcher, I see ICCs ranging from .05 up to .50, depending on the outcome and whether I am modeling longitudinal or cross-sectional data. I would, in general, expect to see higher ICCs in longitudinal, repeated measures data than I would in cross-sectional data. However, there is no hard and fast rule about this.